# LAMP fully installed but MySQL is not working

Tags: apache2, mysql, php, lamp, localhost

I've installed LAMP on Ubuntu 18.04 by following this [link](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-install-linux-apache-mysql-php-lamp-stack-ubuntu-18-04). Now when I entered **localhost** on my browser then it showed Apache2 successfully working UI. But when I tried **localhost/phpmyadmin**, it showed **Not Found** on the browser.

Before this time I've successfully installed and run LAMP. But that time I'd suffered MySQL log in problem (ex. Username Password incorrect problem)

My php version:

```
mefahimrahman@Night-Fury-P452LA:~$ php --version PHP
7.2.15-0ubuntu0.18.04.1 (cli) (built: Feb  8 2019 14:54:22) ( NTS ) Copyright (c) 1997-2018 The PHP Group Zend Engine v3.2.0, Copyright
(c) 1998-2018 Zend Technologies
with Zend OPcache v7.2.15-0ubuntu0.18.04.1, Copyright (c) 1999-2018, by Zend Technologies
```

MySQL version:

> mefahimrahman@Night-Fury-P452LA:~$ mysql --version
>   mysql  Ver 14.14 Distrib 5.7.25, for Linux (x86_64) using  EditLine wrapper

My Question is how can I able to make my LAMP local server workable?

Comment: Have you installed phpmyadmin? Have you configured phpmyadmin?

Comment: Refer to below link if your phpmyadmin throws 404

https://www.digitalocean.com/community/questions/phpmyadmin-got-404-not-found-error-on-nginx-ubuntu-16-04

Comment: Installing the LAMP stack will not install phpMyAdmin by default. You have to set it up in a different step. The tutorial you linked in your post doesn't show how to install phpMyAdmin either. Does the command `mysql --version` work for you?

Comment: @Dan Yes. But I forgot to mention it specifically.

Comment: @vidarlo yes, but this time it is not even asking for the username and password

Comment: @mefahimrahman This means LAMP is actually properly set up, however, you have an issue with your phpMyAdmin installation. Can you add more information on the steps you used to set up phpMyAdmin, or maybe a link to the tutorial you used?

Comment: I've followed this [link] and [this] link. Now whenever I hit localhost/phpmyadmin it shows **403 forbidden**

(https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-install-linux-apache-mysql-php-lamp-stack-ubuntu-18-04)
(https://www.digitalocean.com/community/questions/phpmyadmin-got-404-not-found-error-on-nginx-ubuntu-16-04)